# Python/Seleium: Scraping website with unchanging url

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape [Dubai's Visitor Page](http://www.visitdubai.com/en/shop-dine-relax/directory/D68E832C-A447-4DCB-ADE4-858485D880A5) for all places to dine in Dubai. The page has an unchanging URL but I would like to scrape all 61 pages present on the page. My current code only gets me the names on the first pages. I would like to pull more information; however, I feel I need to get the loop correct before I attempt to pull more information.

```
#import libraries
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


for i in range(1, 11, 1):
    while True:
        baseurl = "http://www.visitdubai.com/en/shop-dine-relax/directory/D68E832C-A447-4DCB-ADE4-858485D880A5"
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get(baseurl)
        for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="divHomeWrap"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li/a/span"""):
            print link.text
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some inspiration from [this post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343258/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-with-an-unchanging-url-python/31343625#31343625) But here is my final code if you want to see.

```
def getnames(driver):
    for name in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="divHomeWrap"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li/a/span"""):
        print name.text

while True:
    getnames(driver)
    nextpage = driver.find_element_by_id("plhcontent_0_hlNext")
    nextpage.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```