# how to scrape multiple pages with static url, request method get

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screen-scraping

first of all, sorry for my english, secondly iam is just 2 week old in python.

right now i use python, module selenium, and chromedriver, page i want to scrape is "http://lpse.maroskab.go.id/eproc4/lelang", the code i use is this :

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")

path =r'F:\python latian\webdriver\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path = path)
driver.get('http://lpse.maroskab.go.id/eproc4/lelang')
sleep(5)
page=bs(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
code=page.find_all(class_="sorting_1")
for xx in code:
   kode=xx.contents[0]
   print(code)
```

but with this code i only get data from the first page, and what i want to accomplised is to scraping the other page,
then i encountered  ([this thread][1]), but the answer in that thread the request method is **"post"**, and in mine is **"get"**. i read there a suggestion to using "urllib.request" but as i know this method only work if i know the url.
thank you
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985758/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-with-an-unchanging-url-python-3

Comment: Do update me on your progress

Comment: i find the workaround, i suppose to use urllib, because in url that i find in XHR i find some parameter that if i change the value i can get the data, but unfortunately for some reason i get error 403 (maybe they initially block urllib)

Comment: It's possible to use urllib. You can post that as another question and I will be happy to help.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, i have post another question in here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179774/scraping-multiple-page-with-urllib-get-response-403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to go about this and iterating over multiple pages is not trivial, your code would need considerable improvements. Since you are new, I will what you need to include and also give an example that you can use it to incorporate into your code.

You would definitely need to use [Explicit Waits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343258/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-with-an-unchanging-url-python) to wait for the invisibility of "loading" indicators.

You would also need an endless loop which we would exit only if the "Next Page" link becomes disabled (no more pages available).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343258/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-with-an-unchanging-url-python) is a good example and use the answer by @alecxe.

Comment: well, iam still confuse, this is beyond my knowledge, i still so dumb for this,  for now i will learn more, and delete this thread, thank you so much sir/miss